# What is the chronological and correct reading order for the Mass Effect series?

Tags: comics, books, mass-effect, chronological-order

There are several books, comics and of course the games for the Mass Effect series. I'd like to know the chronological reading order for all the media related to the universe.

Books:

- Revelation
- Ascension
- Retribution
- Deception

Comics:

- Redemption
- Incursion
- Inquisition
- Evolution
- Conviction
- Invasion
- Homeworlds
- Blasto - Eternity is forever
- He who laughs best
- Foundation

(I think I also remember something about a movie)

Thanks all!

Comment: If you feel the question deserves a downvote please comment so it can be improved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Revelation prologue** – Set in 2157

> It was in 2148, a mere nine years ago” talks about the setting of Evolution so this one comes first.
>   The classified transmission he had received that morning from the base at Shanxi was proof of that.

**Evolution** – 2157 From the description of the first issue we get that this story takes place in the year 2157

> In the year 2157

**Foundation 01** – First text box

> 2161 Three years after first contact war

**Revelation Main Story** – 2165 First Line of Chapter 1

> Eight Years Later 2165

**Foundation 04** – 2168

> Gagarin Station 2168

**He Who Laughs Best** – 2183 – I don’t have this comic but on http://thetimelinesite.com/timelines/7-mass-effect-timeline it is stated as 2183.

**Foundation 02** – 2183 (Wrex hunting Fist links to ME1 story)

**Mass Effect 1**

**Foundation 03** – 2183 (Links to Mass Effect, Read before Eden Prime)

**Homeworlds 02** – 2183 (Links to Mass Effect, Read after Eden Prime)

**Mass Effect: Galaxy** - 2183 – Mobile GameiOS

**Incursion** – 2183

> One week before the collectors attack the Normandy and kill Commander Shepard.

**Mass Effect 2 Prologue** - 2183 (1 month after battle of the Citadel)

**Ascension** – 2183

> In the weeks since the devastating geth assault

**Foundation 05** – 2183

> Nearly a month after the attack on the Citadel

**Foundation 06**

**Redemption 01-04** – Takes place on Omega station

**Mass Effect: Paragon Lost Movie** (First Part 21:30minutes in)

**Foundation 07-13** – All have storylines culminating before the rest of ME2

**Mass Effect: Paragon Lost Movie** (Remainder)

**Mass Effect 2**(rest of game) and **Homeworlds 3** – 2185 Links to ME2 Archangel

**Retribution** - 2186

**Inquisition** - 2186

> Citadel 2186

**Conviction** - 2186

> Days after the annihilation of a Batarian system by Commander Shepard

**Homeworlds 04** – 2186 (Links to shadow broker)

**Invasion** – 2186 (Before Reaper Invasion)

**Infiltrator** – 2186 (Don’t have this one either)

**Mass Effect 3**

**Homeworlds 01** – 2186

> Citadel 2186. Days after the reaper invasion of earth

I've tried to give a bit more detail on why they are ordered as they are, as well as quotes where applicable to indicate the proper order.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the Mass Effect Wiki [Timeline](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline):

- Revelation
- Evolution
- He Who Laughs Best
- Homeworlds 1
- **Mass Effect 1** starts...
- Homeworlds 3
- Mass Effect Galaxy (Game)
- Incursion
- **Mass Effect 2** starts...
- Ascension
- Redemption
- Paragon Lost
- Homeworlds 4
- Retribution
- Inquisition
- Deception
- Conviction
- Invasion
- Infiltrator
- **Mass Effect 3** starts...
- Homeworlds 2

Some of these events overlap in time frame, such as Mass Effect 2 starts before and concludes after all the events in Ascension, Redemption, and Paragon Lost.

*Blasto: Eternity is Forever* is a single issue comic that is based on several films *within* the Mass Effect universe. Therefore it does not conform to the normal timeline.

Comment: I'm reading through them now (at a slower than usual pace) but depending on how specific you want the order. Only the prologue from Revelation comes before evolution. Everything else is after.

Comment: @CandiedMango I'm fine changing it, again I was basing it off the Timeline from the wiki, which just says things like "Revelation Storyline begins" but never says when it ends.

Comment: I'm writing up an answer as I go that quotes the books when they say what the year is. It will however be sometime and I'm happy to keep this here for the time being as it is mostly correct (I had searched the internet and found a variety of different sources) mainly going off individuals which would not be reference-able here :). Lots of different agreements on the actual order though >.> hopefully I will find out once and for all! :D

Comment: It might be possible to determine where *Blasto: Eternity is Forever* goes in the *Blasto* franchise, which would allow us to guesstimate its in-universe publication date.  But given how vague Bioware has been on this point, I am not optimistic.